# smtp remote host responds "550 Sender verify failed"

Tags: smtp, email

A server I'm taking care of uses qmail for MTA. I can send and receive to almost every domain except one or two that give the following error, or something very similar:

```
550-Verification failed for <jonathan@aprimatic.es>
550-No Such User Here
550 Sender verify failed
```

From what I understand from [this article](https://secure.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/en/wiki/Callback_verification) the remote host tries to send an email to my host to see if the mailbox really exists.

I tried the same commands with telnet from my laptop, and i get `250 ok` answers, leading to think that the user does indeed exist.

Why then does the remote host not get the same response I did?

How can I check if traffic from the remote host is indeed routable to my sending host?

Any other sugggestions?

Thanks

Comment: I have had to deal with this in the past and what we did was contact the receiving email server admin, who had to change his settings.  Can you contact them?

Comment: Try telnetting not from your laptop but from the mail server itself.

Comment: From the destination host to the sending host you mean? I would love to do that, but unfortunately I do not have access to the destination host, only the sender.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

This is not your fault. This is a fault of your recipient's server.

Doing "sender verify" is always a bad idea. You have to convince the recipient to stop this behavior as this is not a suitable antispam method.

- [Read this to know how to do this in Postfix, and read between the lines why you SHOULD NOT do this as sender verification](http://www.postfix.org/ADDRESS_VERIFICATION_README.html).
- [Read this carefully to see WHY it is a bad idea](http://www.spamresource.com/2010/12/all-about-email-address-validation.html).

But anything you do to fix it on your side is a waste of time.

Comment: All those stupid arguments in "WHY it is a bad idea" are not compelling absolutely. If you send mail with lame FROM:, it's bad idea and it's your problem. And yeah, it's your fault

Comment: Though your answers is useful in clarifying the problem, it is no solution as one never know which sever will reject the next post

Comment: It's not a solution because it's not your problem... You can't rely on servers to respond to VRFY verbs, and if you do then it's your own problem; not the people that you wont be able to communicate with. RFC2520 (1999) Section 2.11 states that VRFY should be disabled.

Answer (score 4):

This is most likely because you are using a **From** field which differs from the actual mailbox account name.

Some SMTP servers are configured to reject such an inconsistency.

So, for example, if your real account name is `sender@abc.com`, you cannot send emails as `no-reply@abc.com`.

Comment: This was exactly my problem. Changed the "from address" and email started working right away. I'm using cPanel for SMTP.

Answer (score 1):

I had same error. It worked after I added `root:user1@example.com:mail.example.com` line to `/etc/ssmtp/revaliases` file.